# ASP.NET: Call to GetTempPath returns the .NET Framework ASP.NET Temporary Files Folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

We just had a production application go belly up. The error is GetTempPath() is returning the .NET Framework's ASP.NET Temporary Files folder instead of the usual Windows/Temp folder. Obviously something in the environment has changed but what? The application is running in IIS 7.5 under the default ApplicationIdentity account (whatever that is). Is there a way I can override this in the web.config?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, this function returns one of 4 possible values in the following order:

- The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
- The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
- The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
- The Windows directory.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Why don't you update the TMP environment variable on the server and see of that resolves your issue?

Comment: And I would try it if I could figure out what which the friggin account it was and how to log into it. (Did I mention I'm not a fan of how IIS 7.5 does it's accounts?) :)

Comment: Application Identity means it's running under its app pool. You set it so that it loads a profile like a regular user, you might be able to set the appropriate environment variable then: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/03/08/iis-7-tip-3-you-can-now-load-the-user-profile-of-the-application-pool-identity.aspx